# I found most of the ROS packages are in home/user/ros but the latest in /opt/ros/

Tags: ros, setup.sh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

After I finish the beginner level tutorial actually I am a bit lost.. I don't have the 2dnav_pr2 package. I start wandering around the forum. Based on http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_2dnav_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20the%202dnav%20Stack I installed cturtle, diamondback and electric packages.

Then my roscd will lead me to /opt/ros/ instead of /home/user/ros. I found that the last three packages are installed to /opt/ros/. Could anyone explain me the setup.sh?

Now if I run . setup.sh in the /home/user/ros, the roscd cannot be found. quite confusing about the situation. Hope some one help me out and give me instructions on how to perform a simulation...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12526/i-found-most-of-the-ros-packages-are-in-home/user/ros-but-the-latest-in-/opt/ros//) by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 710 on 2012-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-05**:
These days, `setup.sh` is recommended only for non-bash shells. If you source `setup.bash` instead, it will define functions like `roscd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
You could refer to the answer i posted [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/3313/source-command-not-found#5211) which kinda explains how ROS finds its packages and the mistake you could avoid initially.

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-05**:
I suggest you to have ros_workspace as given in the 1st tutorial and setup the environment. So that even your later downloaded packages do not have this problem. Now you can copy them to a workspace folder n setup the envi

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2012-01-05**:
Hi thanks karthik. I think the first beginning when I come to the enviroment configuration I encountered some problem and I changed the PACKAGE_PATH to /home/user/ros/ros.  For these three packages, do i need to reinstall them? I think i spent hours get them installed...or can I just change some parameters to let them work?